# Netbeans failed to use method after SVN update

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

After Tortoise SVN update netbeans refuse to use method from class:

Adding block of code from project:

```
        ...
        }
        if (!f.createNewFile()) {
            throw new IOException("create file error");
        }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(file);
        res = SWConfigServiceManager.importDTBConfig(fn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("importDTB()", e);
    }
    ...
```

Problem is in **importDTBConfig** method call. Netbeans shows that in the class **SWConfigServiceManager**, there's not importDTBConfig method. But.. the method is in the class... Even when I use netbeans hint to create this method, an error is reported that the method is already declared in SWConfigServiceManager class... The import is OK, parameter of called method is OK, method is implemented in SWConfigServiceManager class. Netbeans IDE linking (CTRL + click on class) redirects me to the SWConfigServiceManager class.

It's a netbeans bug? I had some problems after updating my project from SVN for a few times... In this case I can not build the project because of IDE error...

Comment: I am not an netbeans expert; but from my eclipse background: did you try to  fully "clean & rebuild" all your projects? Did you restart netbeans? Final note: at least for eclipse, git support works **much** better than any of the SVN plugins. So I switched to use "git svn" lately; which basically allows you to have a local git repository ... that actually bridges to a remote SVN server. Now all the "using SVN within my IDE" headache **completely** vanished.

Comment: Yes clean + build or IDE restart doesnt work... If I understand it right your advice is to use git... I can not do it because the whole company uses SVN :/

Comment: No. My company is still using a SVN server to store our source code. But on my local machine, I am using "git svn" which looks like git to me, and my IDE; but which can talk to the remote SVN server. So this is a "single person" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should try clean and build since it might not do automatic build when you update your source files (it does by default but maybe the setting was changed).

After that, either it gives you a compilation error (perhaps the soure merging ended in a problem in the source file where the method is and that is why Netbeans was still refering a previous build of that method) or the problem is solved :)

Comment: Thank you for answer, however clean (and build) does not work...
error: cannot find symbol - is shown like in ID error hint

Comment: is the method you call a static one? because from the caller code, it looks like it is a static method.

Comment: Yes, it is ...
public static boolean importDTBConfig(final String backupStoragePathAndName)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache will help. After that clean + build (in my case build with dependencies) fixed the problem. It seems that netbeans was using previous compiled class file which was not correct after the svn update. Also I want to thank you for trying to help.